# Is it possible to update a REG_BINARY value in Windows Registry with install4j 'Set a Value' action

Tags: install4j

I have install4j creating a windows service but I need to set the restart delay to a value.  This value is stored in a `REG_BINARY` field.

Is there a way to set the failure restart delay when creating a windows service.  and if not, is there a way to set a `REG_BINARY` value in the windows registry so I can set this value after install4j creates the service?

Note: I tried just setting the 'Value' field using the hex digits like it is displayed via windows regedit (i.e.  00 00 00 00 03 00 14 00 00 EA 00 00 EA 00 etc) but it ended up changing the registry value from a `REG_BINARY` type to a `REG_SZ` type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the failure restart delay when creating a windows service.

Currently not.

> and if not, is there a way to set a REG_BINARY value in the windows registry so I can set 
>   this value after install4j creates the service?

The "Set a value in the Windows registry" action does not support this, but you can use the API to do that:

```
byte[] value = ...;
WinRegistry.setValue(RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
    "keyName", "valueName", value);
```

The value must be of type `byte[]` to create a registry entry of type `REG_BINARY`.